# Access a Shared Screen through BEQSRequest

Tags: c#, wpf, request, bloomberg

I am using BEQSRequst to access the EQS Screen through C#.Its working fine.
My problem is when I try to access the Shared Scrreens I get a Message saying"Invalid Screeen name".How can I access a Shared Screen  through BEQSRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it worked for me.While Creating the request Set screenType as PRIVATE.

```
            Request request = service.CreateRequest("BeqsRequest");
            request.Set("screenName", "My Screen Name");
            request.Set("screenType", "PRIVATE");
```